# Sending Arbitrary data with notification style Firebase cloud messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have a short question. I want to send a custom value from a cloud function
which listens for onWrite events in the Firebase Database.
 My Code for the Cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/chats/notifications/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {
  var values = event.data.val();

const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: values.username,
        body: values.message,
        sound: "default",
        displayName: values.username,
        UiD:  values.recieverUiD
    },
};
const options = {
    priority: "high"
};
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(values.recieverUiD, payload, options);});
```

And now the database structure looks like this:

chats

-notifications

-some ID

-username: fdsdf

-uid: 9043554

How can I send the UiD to my device? the way like in the code does not work with displayName... how am I supposed to do it

Comment: I'm not cheat on the db structure or what's not working

Comment: I send notifications by supscibing to a topic with my UID. And in the node script I send it to the topic. And know I just want to know how i can send custom values and recieve them in my FirebaseMessagingService with remoteMessage.getData.get("userUiD");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass arbitrary key value pairs in a notification message by adding a data key the same level as the notification key in your payload:

```
{"notification": {...},
"data" : {
      "uid": 9043554
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just forgot it and wasn't able to find it on Google

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the notification token for each user in your database.

[Here the documentation to get this notification token.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token)

[Here a great sample to send Push Notifications with Firebase Cloud Functions.](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications)

To custom your payload :

```
{
  "to": "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
  "notification": {
    "body": "great match!",
    "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "icon": "myicon"
  },
  "data": {
    "Nick": "Mario",
    "Room": "PortugalVSDenmark"
  }
}
```

[Data message FCM documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages)

Comment: This is working fine. But how can I send custom values to my device?? For Example userUiD,...

Comment: Do you know how I can delete the parent in the database from the Firebase Script??

Comment: @KarlWolf you have to use Firebase Functions, and the good about "notifications" plus "data" is that can be send using the Firebase web console, however, be careful the behavior can be complex. This is how it works on Android, in case it helps you: Combined push if the app is in background then the visual notification is by default and the data is accessible when the user click, if it is on foreground visual notification is custom and data is always available.